# How to merge ReLU after quantization aware training

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, quantization-aware-training

I have a network which contains Conv2D layers followed by ReLU activations, declared as such:

```
x = layers.Conv2D(self.hparams['channels_count'], kernel_size=(4,1))(x)
x = layers.ReLU()(x)
```

And it is ported to TFLite with the following representaiton:

[Basic TFLite network without Q-aware training](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcZWq.png)

However, after performing quantization-aware training on the network and porting it again, the ReLU layers are now explicit in the graph:

[TFLite network after Q-aware training](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DralW.png)

This results in them being processed separately on the target instead of during the evaluation of the Conv2D kernel, inducing a 10% performance loss in my overall network.

Declaring the activation with the following implicit syntax does not produce the problem:

```
x = layers.Conv2D(self.hparams['channels_count'], kernel_size=(4,1), activation='relu')(x)
```

[Basic TFLite network with implicit ReLU activation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19YVu.png)

[TFLite network with implicit ReLU after Q-aware training](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uO6RB.png)

However, this restricts the network to basic ReLU activation, whereas I would like to use ReLU6 which cannot be declared in this way.

Is this a TFLite issue? If not, is there a way to prevent the ReLU layer from being split? Or alternatively, is there a way to manually merge the ReLU layers back into the Conv2D layers after the quantization-aware training?

**Edit:**
QA training code:

```
def learn_qaware(self):
quantize_model = tfmot.quantization.keras.quantize_model
self.model = quantize_model(self.model)

training_generator = SCDataGenerator(self.training_set)
validate_generator = SCDataGenerator(self.validate_set)

self.model.compile(
            optimizer=self.configure_optimizers(qa_learn=True),
            loss=self.get_LLP_loss(),
            metrics=self.get_metrics(),
            run_eagerly=config['eager_mode'],
        )
self.model.fit(
    training_generator,
    epochs = self.hparams['max_epochs'],
    batch_size = 1,
    shuffle = self.hparams['shuffle_curves'],
    validation_data = validate_generator,
    callbacks = self.get_callbacks(qa_learn=True),
)
```

Quantized TFLite model generation code:

```
def tflite_convert(classifier):
output_file = get_tflite_filename(classifier.model_path)

# Convert the model to the TensorFlow Lite format without quantization
saved_shape = classifier.model.input.shape.as_list()
fixed_shape = saved_shape
fixed_shape[0] = 1
classifier.model.input.set_shape(fixed_shape) # Force batch size to 1 for generation
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(classifier.model)
classifier.model.input.set_shape(saved_shape)

# Set the optimization flag.
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
# Enforce integer only quantization
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]
converter.inference_input_type = tf.int8
converter.inference_output_type = tf.int8
# Provide a representative dataset to ensure we quantize correctly.
if config['eager_mode']:
    tf.executing_eagerly()
def representative_dataset():
    for x in classifier.validate_set.get_all_inputs():
        rs = x.reshape(1, x.shape[0], 1, 1).astype(np.float32)
        yield([rs])

converter.representative_dataset = representative_dataset
model_tflite = converter.convert()

# Save the model to disk
open(output_file, "wb").write(model_tflite)

return TFLite_model(output_file)
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant section of code for your quantized-aware training?

Comment: @daverim Code added, thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

I have found a workaround which works by instantiating a non-trained version of the model, then copying over the weights from the quantization aware trained model before converting to TFLite.

This seems like quite a hack, so I'm still on the lookout for a cleaner solution.

Code for the workaround:

```
def dequantize(self):
    if not hasattr(self, 'fp_model') or not self.fp_model:
        self.fp_model = self.get_default_model()

    def find_layer_in_model(name, model):
        for layer in model.layers:
            if layer.name == name:
                return layer
        return None

    def find_weight_group_in_layer(name, layer):
        for weight_group in quant_layer.trainable_weights:
            if weight_group.name == name:
                return weight_group
        return None

    for layer in self.fp_model.layers:
        if 'input' in layer.name or 'quantize_layer' in layer.name:
            continue
        
        QUANT_TAG = "quant_"
        quant_layer = find_layer_in_model(QUANT_TAG+layer.name,self.model)
        if quant_layer is None:
            raise RuntimeError('Failed to match layer ' + layer.name)

        for i, weight_group in enumerate(layer.trainable_weights):
            quant_weight_group = find_weight_group_in_layer(QUANT_TAG+weight_group.name, quant_layer)
            if quant_weight_group is None:
                quant_weight_group = find_weight_group_in_layer(weight_group.name, quant_layer)
                if quant_weight_group is None:
                    raise RuntimeError('Failed to match weight group ' + weight_group.name)

            layer.trainable_weights[i].assign(quant_weight_group)

    self.model = self.fp_model
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `activation=tf.nn.relu6` to use ReLU6 activation.

Comment: Unfortunately, when doing this, the quantization aware training module then does not recognize the activation function as a ReLU. It needs to be passed as a custom object, which produces this error down the line:
`ValueError: Only some Keras activations under tf.keras.activations are supported. For other activations, use Quantizer directly, and update layer config using QuantizeConfig.`

It seems it then necessitates a custom quantization procedure and I haven't found any example for doing this. This seems a bit overkill for something the QA learning already knows how to do.